# Path Distance Allocation tool in ArcGIS Pro, How to infer if source is a road network?

Tags: openstreetmap, arcgis-pro, distance, cost-path

From what I understand, the tool, given a source like a point on map will give the least to highest cost to travel from that point throughout the raster.

If my understanding is right, now If I give a network of road as the souce like OSM road network, I get the rasterized roads with each pixel of the road having a cost. But I'm not sure how to infer this? What is the source here? Is it just telling me which roads have least cost and high cost irrespective of source or is my entire understanding incorrect?

Reference image of road network and output of the Path Distance Allocation algorithm:

[image]

Comment: Given a source like a line on map, it will give the least to highest cost to travel from that line throughout the raster. The line itself would have zero cost.

Comment: @Vince so the result I got look like something like that of a traffic map? Where the same line at different points in raster is showing different costs?

Comment: Your "understanding" (and my restatement thereof) describes a different tool. **Path** Distance Allocation is different from **Cost** Distance Allocation. Review the [Path Distance Allocation documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/path-distance-allocation.htm) to better understand what it does.

Comment: @Vince `The Path Distance tools are comparable to the Cost Distance tools in that both determine the minimum accumulative travel cost from or to a source for each location on a raster surface` The only diff. it says it accounts for `actual surface distance`. Hence the confusion remains

Comment: Well, I guess you need to understand what Cost Distance does first. It has little to do with what a traffic map looks like. It's more like what a "You're *Really* Lost! If you don't have at least *N* days food and water, you need to set off your emergency beacon now!" sign deployment exercise for a wilderness area would look like, where being on the path means you're not lost, and a hiking difficulty surface is used to determine how far the walk to "safety" will be.